# How do i get the table of contents to just include the sections and subsection in beamer when using pauses?

Tags: beamer

I have put several pauses in throughout the presentation and now the table of contents has been split by the pauses. I want the table of contents to show each section and subsection once though.

For example if before I had a section called Bob and then I put a pause in on a slide in that section, I would then seemingly have 2 sections called Bob on the contents page.
Like below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \section{bob}
       bob bob bob
\pause 
        bob bob bob
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then show us the `bob.tex` file, please ;-)

Comment: `bob.tex` now above, enjoy :P

Comment: Is there a reason you need to declare your "section" inside of the frame? When the "section" is declared prior to the frame, everything works as expected.

Comment: @cptnjtk: You should transfer your comment into an answer!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: OK, thanks! I was not sure if I was missing something from the op or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring your `\section{...}` before you begin a frame you will fix the issue of having duplicate section titles in the table of contents. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{bob}
    \begin{frame}
       bob bob bob
     \pause 
       bob bob bob
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```